# This SR latch built with 180nm CMOS does not work in ltspice. How do I fix its behavior and parameters?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, digital-logic, ltspice, cmos

EDIT: I copied over the latch from another larger model that had Vdd defined, but missed it when copying over the design. However, after adding in Vdd, I still run into this confusing issue where the R seems to trigger Q and not S.

I used [these](http://scale.engin.brown.edu/classes/EN1600S08/tutorials/180nm.lib) 180nm mosfets to build this SR latch:
[image]

I used the nmos4 and pmos4 and added a spice directive with the models. I sized the nmos as L = .18um and W = .5u and the PMOS as L= .18u and W=1u (to get more symmetrical rise fall time, though Im not sure by what factor exactly I would need to scale the width):

[image]

However, even though I followed a regular schematic for an SR latch it does not work. When the S and R are triggered it seems that R triggers Q and not S.  Then again, not all the parameters are recognized by ltspice and Im not sure how to get around that other than by using another transistor. **Is there a way to make this current design work? Also, any chance someone could let me know if the warnings I am seeing are a clear need to fix a particular thing in the circuit?**

[image]
[[image]

Comment: Look at the top CMOS stack, when S=1, Q=0. Is that what you desire?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see a power source providing Vdd in your schematic. How would you expect that to work?

The spikes you see are just capacitive coupling.

Also, you mislabeled your nodes. Q and Qb are reversed.

Comment: yes that is true. Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to add in Vdd. It had been defined in the other segment of the circuit I did not include in this particular schematic